Trying to build sitemap from scratch
It's only a 5-page website. The current google sitemap is inaccurate and so are other sitemap generated services (they're very minor inaccuracies, but I'm positive that they're negatively affecting my SEO.
I just find it hard to believe that it's so complicated (for me anyway) to build a new sitemap with those minor corrections.
I tried using notepad, sublime, slick something, frog something, I don't know how many I've tried. I've had 5-6 email correspondences with sites sort of like this one.
I've probably spent 200 hrs over the past 4 months trying to figure out how to build a 5-page sitemap from scratch. What's really heartbreaking is that I sincerely think this can be done in 2-3 minutes by someone who knows what they're doing.
